# How to propagate state to the root of nested tree from a deep node without using Flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am rendering a nested comment tree, I am not able to figure how to update the tree data present in the comment container from one of the deeply nested comments. I have created a basic fiddle representing the scenario, check it out [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nandwana92/6cLaam60/1/). The button in each node is supposed to invert the value of "likes" property, which should be coming from the state in parent container. Looking for a non redux solution.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tree: [
        {
          id: "cake",
          likes: true,
          kids: [
            {
              id: "banana",
              likes: false,
              kids: []
            },
            {
              id: "rocket",
              likes: false,
              kids: [
                {
                  id: "homework",
                  likes: true,
                  kids: [
                    {
                      id: "something",
                      likes: true,
                      kids: []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tree.map(value => <Kid value={value} />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Kid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{margin: '20px', border: '5px dashed #DCEDC8'}}>
        <span>id: {this.props.value.id}</span><br />
        <span>likes: {this.props.value.likes ? 'yes' : 'no'}</span><br />
        <button>invert</button>
        {this.props.value.kids.length
          ? this.props.value.kids.map(value => <Kid value={value} />)
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Looking for something like this ? This assumes the id's are unique. https://jsfiddle.net/marudhupandiyang/74hL0r7a

Comment: @Panther This will work for my case, I too was thinking on similar lines. The parsing will be very costly for a lot of nodes and nesting though.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation for Redux state is to keep it normalized, something like this:

```
this.state = {
  normalized: [
    cake: {likes: true, kids: ["banana", "rocket"]}
    banana: {likes: false, kids: []},
    rocket: {likes: false, kids: ["homework"]},
    homework: {likes: true, kids: ["something"]},
    something: {likes: true, kids: []},
  ],
  root: "cake",
};
```

Then, if you have an id, you would refer to an item with `this.state.normalized[id]`

For example, to traverse the tree and apply a function to every node, you would do:

```
function traverse(node, func) {
  func(node);

  for (let i = 0, len = node.kids.length; i < len; i++) {
    traverse(this.state.normalized[node.kids[i]]);
  }
}

traverse(this.state.normalized[this.state.root]);
```

Normalizr can be useful to normalize nested API responses if you don't want to code your own solution.

If you really want to keep an immutable tree in your state, Immutable.js is good at letting your performantly alter a tree in a single line without mutating it.

Comment: Thanks, ended up doing something similar. Not using Redux but have converted the state to a flat object.

Comment: Yeah, sorry if that was unclear. Redux is pretty liberal about the format of your state so it's usually whatever you'd have in your component state. It's just where the recommendation comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that does what you wanted. 
There are a lot of things here that you need to pay attention to be able to understand how it works. 
While rendering each of the kid, the parent path and kid's id becomes a kid's path. When the button is clicked this path gets passed to the Parent component where the state gets manipulated using this path.

This assumes that id will be unique for siblings.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tree: [
        {
          id: "cake",
          likes: true,
          kids: [
            {
              id: "banana",
              likes: false,
              kids: []
            },
            {
              id: "rocket",
              likes: false,
              kids: [
                {
                  id: "homework",
                  likes: true,
                  kids: [
                    {
                      id: "something",
                      likes: true,
                      kids: []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
    this.onInvertHandler = this.onInvertHandler.bind(this);
  }
    onInvertHandler(path) {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        const pathKeys = path.split(':');
      let obj = prevState['tree'];

      for(let i=0;i<pathKeys.length;i++) {
        obj = i >0 ? obj.kids : obj;
        obj = obj.find((el)=>{ return el.id == pathKeys[i] });
      }
      obj['likes'] = !obj['likes'];
      return prevState;
    })
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.tree.map(value => <Kid value={value} path = {value.id} onInvertHandler={this.onInvertHandler}/>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Kid extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onInvertHandler = this.onInvertHandler.bind(this);
  }
    onInvertHandler(p) {
    let params = typeof p === 'string' ? p : this.props.path;
    this.props.onInvertHandler(params);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{margin: '20px', border: '5px dashed #DCEDC8'}}>
        <span>id: {this.props.value.id}</span><br />
        <span>likes: {this.props.value.likes ? 'yes' : 'no'}</span><br />
        <button onClick = {this.onInvertHandler}>invert</button>
        {this.props.value.kids.length
          ? this.props.value.kids.map(value => <Kid value={value} path = {this.props.path + ':'+value.id} onInvertHandler={this.onInvertHandler}/>)
          : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("container"));
```